# After partitioning a table, how can we see data in each partition

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE  Laptop 
PARTITION BY LIST(Id) ( PARTITION pNorth VALUES IN (0,1), 
                        PARTITION pEast VALUES IN (2,3), 
                        PARTITION pWest VALUES IN (4,5), 
                        PARTITION pCentral VALUES IN (6,7) );
```

schema-Electronics table-Laptop

Tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.partitions  
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='Electronics'  
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Laptop' 
  AND PARTITION_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

but this gives information about the partitions, but i want to check the data inside each partition.  Is it possible or not if yes please tell me how can i find

Comment: *i want to check the data inside each partition* What do you mean? what result do you want to get?

Comment: as u can see there are four partitions so 8 rows are there with Ids (0 to 7),  each row has data that is partitioned in four parts, that data only i want to see with different partition names.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html

Comment: *so 8 rows are there with Ids (0 to 7)* Not "are". May exists (and may not). Simply execute `SELECT Id FROM Laptop;` and check returned values. Don't be afraid - the record cannot be posessed in non-matched partition.

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon got the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"we can get the data from each partition using that partition name"

SELECT * FROM table_name PARTITION (your partition name);